# Zend Framework 2 - trailing slashes in route

Tags: php, zend-framework2, directory-structure

Havin in a Zend Module following structure

Name of Module

- Test

  - config
  - src
  - view

    - layout
    - test

      - index

        - index.phtml
      - login

        - index.phtml
      - register

        - index.phtml
  - Module.php

Now when accessing website for example for login file it will be as following http://justsite.something.com/login

**Problem** Need to change to http://justsite.something.com/login/ for that i added to login folder another folder index and there putted index.phtml file like this

- login

  - index

    - index.phtml

But that doesn't seem to work. Should i change in LoginController.php for this to work?

**module.confing.php**

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'test' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/test',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' =>'Test\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes'  => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' =>
                        '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' =>
                            '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' =>
                            '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'login' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/login/', // PUT HERE WHATEVER YOU WANT
                'defaults' => array(  // AND MAP THAT URL TO CONTROLLER/ACTION
                    '__NAMESPACE__' =>'Test\Controller',                    
                    'controller' => 'Login',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

**Fixed** Just added

```
'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes'  => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' =>
                        '/[:controller[/:action]/]',
```

Comment: Why do you need the path with a slash in the end without any string following?

Comment: Such are the requirements of a project.

Answer (score 1):

Like @tasmaniski wrote you don't need to make changes to LoginController or whatever, all comes down to your route config. You are not the only one who wants *"trailing slashes"* in his routes, [here you can read how you can achieve this](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/zend-framework-2-trailing-slash/).

Apparently you need to put it between []

```
'route'    => '/[:controller[/[:action[/]]]]',
```

Hope that solves it for you.

**NOTE** *Some people suggest using a rewrite rule for this, I  thought this might be worth mentioning* too.

Comment: Look at my **Fixed** block in main post.

Comment: @user3904245 does the asterisk in your solution not make the controller and action optional?

Comment: i just put them to show what i added. I will remove for misunderstandings.

Comment: Note that for this to work, route must be of `'type' => 'Segment'`

Answer (score 0):

No matter what is your forlder structure. You need to make a change in the config file module.config.php, section  "routes".

You only need to put in "route" value with slash at the end and map it to controller/action.

```
'routes' => array(
    'login' => array(
        'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/login/', // PUT HERE WHATEVER YOU WANT
            'defaults' => array(     // AND MAP THAT URL TO CONTROLLER/ACTION
                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Login',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I think you gave right what i needed but when i made changes that are in **module.confing.php** section above it doesn't work.

Comment: hm.. try to set something else like 'route' => '/dummy-test/' and tell  what is the error when you type in browser http://url/dummy-test/ ??

Comment: Your ideea was good but all what was needed was in **Fixed** block. Thanks anyway.

Comment: :) in that fixed block is all what I said. To put in route section slash at the end ....